# Need some help figuring out BB4Win or any of its varieties: does it replace windows explorer?

Tags: shell

I don't really care too much about replacing original Windows the desktop, taskbar and system tray. I really dislike the new Windows 7/Vista Windows Explorer:

[image: Screenshot here]

What I'm trying to figure out is whether BB4Win or its plugins have a replacement for it. The bb4win website pretty much doesn't make sense to me. I'm using Win7 64 bit.

---

Also, off-topic ... I was looking at a related question on this site here:
https://superuser.com/questions/17842/good-windows-shell-replacement

Comment: You don't have a high enough reputation (yet) to write comments. That will come with time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with Total Commander from [Ghisler](http://www.ghisler.com/). It has a lot of neat functionality and although not free, is fully functional with a startup nag screen.

(Disclaimer: I have bought a licence for Total Commander.)